# Dissolve (merge) polygons QGIS based on (non exact) attribute values

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, merge, dissolve

I am a fairly new user of QGIS having a question regarding dissolve functionality.

I am working with the [NUTS-2 shapefiles](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts) provided by EU, which I have imported in QGIS. To ease the discussion, I have created a new layer with only Denmark and Netherlands as you can see in the picture below.

[image: DK and NL]

The corresponding attribute table is the following.

[image: Attribute table]

The fields describe the ID and name for each NUTS node, as well as the country code. I have introduced a new attribute field, called Merge_attr.

Based on the aforementioned, I have managed to dissolve the polygons with the same attribute value of Merge_attr. However, I would like to dissolve polygons based on the Merge_attr value only when they belong to the same country and potentially only when they are adjacent.

Is it possible to dissolve or merge polygons that have a "valued" attribute which is not exactly the same but similar (i.e. under some other condition). For example, would it be possible to merge polygons that belong to the same country and the difference of their "Merge_attr" values is smaller than 0.5?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question.  We use a "Focused question/Best answer" model, so multiple questions make it difficult to choose among (often partial) answers.  Please [Edit] the Question to ask one question.

Comment: Also feel free to ask your other questions in separate threads.

Comment: The question isn't specific enough, think of the situation where you have candidate polygons A,B,C with attributes 0.1,0.4,0.7. In this case, for a threshold of 0.5, polygon B should be dissolved with A and with C, but A and C must not be dissolved together. The compromise solution will be to add a new column where you group the polygons using intervals of Merge_attr, and dissolve with that column. you shuld look at clustering algorithms if you want to find optimal intervals with certain restrictions in interval length or number of items in an unsupervised way.

Comment: Dissolve will only drop common edges when Polygons are adjacent. Maybe you just need to concatenate Country to the end of Merge_att. You may need to convert to Single Part, at the and, to split Multipart geometries.

Comment: @klewis Dissolving will create one multipolygon for each common field-value.  Even if they are not adjecent.  But, if you then do 'multipart to singlepart' you get what you need

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it in two steps.  Both algorithms can be found under Processing > Processing toolbox

1/ **Dissolve** your features based on 2 fields: `CNTR_CODE` and `Merge_attr`.

To select the desired fields, click `...` next to `Dissolve field(s) [optional]`

[image]

2/ **Split the results** from step one with `multipart to singlepart` algorithm.

[image]

**If it is a repetitive task**, you can combine the two algorithms into one, by using the graphical modeller.  A good tutorial about this can be found here: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_graphical_modeler.html